# Why does Entity Framework create a new entity when I try to associate an existing one?

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship (Users to skills), and when I try to associate an existing skill to a user, it always creates a new one.

User:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

Skill:

```
public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasMany<Skill>(user => user.Skills)
            .WithMany();
    }
```

Creating the association:

```
public ActionResult Skills(SkillsViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.NewSkill)
            && !user.Skills
            .Where(sk => sk.Name == viewModel.NewSkill)
            .Any())
        {
            var foundSkill = this.db.Skills
                .Where(sk => sk.Name == viewModel.NewSkill)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if(foundSkill != null)
            {
                user.Skills.Add(foundSkill);
            }
            else
            {
                user.Skills.Add(new Skill()
                    {
                        Name = viewModel.NewSkill
                    });
            }
        }

        if(viewModel.SelectedSkillId > 0)
        {
            var foundSkill = this.db.Skills.Find(viewModel.SelectedSkillId);


            user.Skills.Add(foundSkill);
        }

        this.UserManager.Update(user);

        return RedirectToAction("skills");
    }
```

I've stepped through, and verified that I do indeed get a 'foundSkill' from the database, but after I add it to the user, and save the user, the skill associated to the user is not the one I found, but a new one with the same  name and different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The UserManager was being loaded with one DbContext, and I was trying to associate a Skill loaded from a different DbContext.

Quick hack to test and fix this was to load the user from the same DbContext as the Skills, update the user, save the DbContext.

Longer term solution would be to ensure that everything uses the same DbContext per request.